# Bookmarklet not working on IE9

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9, frontend, bookmarklet

This code works on Firefox and Chrome but not IE9. It even works on the same domain in IE9 but fails on other domains. Console shows me a SCRIPT1002 : Syntax Error. I have this code in a jsp and loading it into a script tag using {domain}/path from my controller.

```
   (
        function(){
           var v = "1.9.1";
           if (window.jQuery === undefined || window.jQuery.fn.jquery < v ) {
           var done = false;
         var script = document.createElement("script");
         script.src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/" + v + "/jquery.min.js";
         script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if (!done && (!this.readyState || this.readyState == "loaded" || this.readyState == "complete")) {
         done = true;
            initBookmarklet();
        }
        };      
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);   
            } else {
                initBookmarklet();
            } 


            function initBookmarklet(){
                //do stuff here
            }
        }());
```

Comment: you might have a cross domain issue when trying to check the readyState.. you might have to load jquery blindly

Comment: I had commented out the entire section. And I still get the same error. Line 4 Character 1 is where the error is according to IE9.

Comment: try removing the    (
        function(){        }()); part...

Answer (score 0):

try writing it like this

```
var v = "1.9.1";
if (window.jQuery === undefined || window.jQuery.fn.jquery < v) {
    var done = false;
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/" + v + "/jquery.min.js";
    script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (!done && (!this.readyState || this.readyState == "loaded" || this.readyState == "complete")) {
            done = true;
            initBookmarklet();
        }
    };
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
} else {
    initBookmarklet();
}


function initBookmarklet() {
    //do stuff here
}
```